# Draw pgfornament between nodes without drawing line

Tags: tikz-pgf

The `pgfornament` package offers `to [ornament= ...]` to place an ornament between nodes. But when I use this in a `tikzpicture` with `\draw`, it draws a line between the nodes in addition to drawing the node. This is even a problem with the example in the manual, which I adapt for this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (B) at (5,2) {};
\draw [help lines,color=black!60]  (0,0) grid (5,2);
\draw [fill=black!30]  (A) circle (2pt) (B) circle (2pt);
\draw [orange] (A)  to [ornament=88]   (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: typeset result]

Note the thin line between the two nodes in addition to the ornament. How can I eliminate this? If I `\draw[transparent]`, the ornament is also transparent. If I use a dash pattern `on 0pt off 3pt` I get little dots every three points.

Comment: You have other examples in the doc below this one with `\path` instead of `\draw`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very simple: use `\path` instead of `\draw`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {};
\node (B) at (5,2) {};
\draw [help lines,color=black!60]  (0,0) grid (5,2);
\draw [fill=black!30]  (A) circle (2pt) (B) circle (2pt);
\path [orange] (A)  to [ornament=88]   (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you wish the ornament not to enter the circles,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,draw,fill=black!30,inner sep=2pt}]
\draw [help lines,color=black!60]  (0,0) grid (5,2);
\node[bullet] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[bullet] (B) at (5,2) {};
\path (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=0] (AA) 
coordinate[pos=1] (BB) [orange] (AA)  to [ornament=88]   (BB);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]